# Method naming conventions. Should the method be named getX(), if the there's no corresponding setX()?

Tags: oop, naming-conventions, readability, coding-style

Say I got an Employee class that has a hire date data member. This member only get set one time only and it is constant too. So it'll get initialised when the object is created.

If I want the class to have a method that returns the hire date, what's better:

```
getHireDate();
```

Or just:

```
hireDate();
```

Am I thinking too much :D ?

Comment: The conventions will vary depending on what language/framework you're using. I'm guessing Java, in which case I would personally go for `getHireDate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just

```
getHireDate();
```

is fine. It doesn't need a 'set' method to be proper OO.

Edit: if you haven't yet, read some Java Coding Style docs... they're simple enough, and standard coding conventions make everybody' life easier. I just found this: [Java Programming Style Guidelines](http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html). Good reading.